# Image Alt & Title not displaying because Z-index

Tags: html, css, firefox, title, alt

Here's my problem, I have several images in my HTML that are ordered with z-index. But the attributes Alt & Title of image at the bottom won't show in Firefox & Chrome (IE works...).
Is there a way? Thank you!

```
<img src="images/one.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;" alt="This one" title="This one"/> 
<img src="images/two.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;" alt="" title=""/> 
<img src="images/three.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;" alt="" title=""/>
```

The third image (`three.png`) is transparent layer that covers the other two images. I want the alt are title of the first one (`one.png`) to show. Sorry for the laq of explanations, easy problem seem to the hardests to explain :)

**UPDATE**

Ok here's the script that a made :

```
`$('.animated').each(function(index) {

    var attr = $(this).attr('title');
    if (!attr) {
} else{
        var newId = 'wrapper_' + index;
        $(this).wrap('<div id="' + newId + '"></div>');
        var tit = $(this).attr('title');
        var pst = $(this).css('margin-top');
        var stp = $(this).css('margin-left');
        $('#' + newId).prepend('<div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;width:' + $(this).width() + 'px;left:50%;top:50%;height:' + $(this).height() + 'px;margin-left:' + stp + ';margin-top:' + pst + ';" title="' + tit + '"></div>');
    }
});`
```

So it means that when an image has a title a div is created on it with a huge zindex.

Comment: further explanation? no one can help you when you're giving such a brief description.

Comment: Ok, let's imagine :

<img src="images/one.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;" alt="This one" title="This one"/>
<img src="images/two.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;" alt="" title=""/>
<img src="images/three.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;" alt="" title=""/>

The third image (three.png) is transparent layer that covers the other two images.
I want the alt are title of the first one (one.png) to show.
Sorry for the laq of explanations, easy problem seem to the hardests to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my post was deleted please see below:

If you have a transparent image overlaying the other two then the alt and title tags will pull from the transparent layer on top of the other two as it can't recognise the other two underneath.

If you want the title and alt text of the first image ONLY to show then assign these values to the transparent layer.

IE is probably rendering the alt text for the image, which other browsers don't render when an image is present.

Comment: @casperOne - can you please tell me why you decided to delete my previous Answer? Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to get the title element and show it with jquery?

Comment: `$('#imageID').attr('title', 'This One');` should change the title element of an image. You could use this in a function that says when (image 1) is shown display the title of image 3 to 'This One'.

Comment: The fact is that a don't know the content of the title.
My BO puts a class (animated) to every image, so I made this code :

'$(".animated").each(function () {
 var attr = $(".animated").attr('title');
 if(attr !== undefined) {
  this.hover(
  function(){
   alert (attr);
 });
}});'

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Try this `$(".animated").each(function () { var attr = $(".animated").attr('title'); if(attr !== undefined) { $(this).hover( function(){ alert(attr) }); }});`

Comment: Your `this` statement needs to look like `$(this)`

Comment: It does not seem to work, I have even tried something like :
`$(".animated").each(function(){
 $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
});` 

And nothing...

Comment: That works for me, have you placed the `<script>` after the `HTML`, for this example the jQuery needs to run after the images are present and so need to be after. Also make sure you're calling jQuery with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` in the `<head>`